# Как получить содержимое круглых и фигурных скобок первого уровня?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я имею следующую структуру:

```
(Q){(W){g}(E){z}}
```

Мне необходимо достать то, что находится в круглых и фигурных скобках первого уровня. Т.е.

```
Q и (W){g}(E){z}
```

Пробовал `"\((.+?)\){.*?}"` но это обрезает последнюю фигурную скобку.

Comment: Какой диалект регулярных выражений используется ? Возможны ли внутри первых круглых скобок еще круглые скобки ?

Comment: @Mike Круглые скобки содержат имя параметра, фигурные содержат параметры. Параметр может содержать другие параметры.

Comment: Это PHP, C#, Java(Script)?\?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew для меня это не имело особого значения. Мне необходимо было понять свою ошибку. C#

Comment: В C#  все данные ниже ответы не работают, так как в нем нет поддержки рекурсии в регулярных выражениях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# можно использовать балансирующие группы:

```
\((?<val1>(?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!)))\){(?<val2>(?>[^{}]+|(?<w>{)|(?<-w>}))*(?(w)(?!)))}
```

[См. демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%28%28%3F%3Cval1%3E%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%5C%28%29%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%5C%29%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%29%5C%29%7B%28%3F%3Cval2%3E%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Cw%3E%7B%29%7C%28%3F%3C-w%3E%7D%29%29*%28%3F%28w%29%28%3F!%29%29%29%7D&i=%28Q%28abc%29%29%7B%28W%29%7Bg%7D%28E%29%7Bz%7D%7D)

- `\(` - открывающая скобка `)`
- `(?<val1>(?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!)))` - все, что между `(` и `)`
- `\)` - закрывающая скобка `)`
- `{` - открывающая скобка `{`
- `(?<val2>(?>[^{}]+|(?<w>{)|(?<-w>}))*(?(w)(?!)))` - все, что между `{` и `}`
- `}` - закрывающая скобка `}`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [рекурсивный шаблон](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php), например в таком варианте

```
/\(((?>[^()]+|(?R))*)\)|{((?>[^{}]+|(?R))*)}/g
```

Результат будет в первой или второй группе в зависимости от вида скобок.

Пример тут https://regex101.com/r/HRABRe/1

Answer (score 3):

Для обработки вложенности скобок в регулярных выражениях используются рекурсивные проверки. Для первой группы круглых скобок, в случае если в них могут быть еще круглые скобки, это выглядит так:

```
(                 # начинаем первую группу захвата
 \(               # первый символ - круглая скобка
   (              # вторая группа захвата - требуемый результат
    (?:
     (?1) |       # внутри которой может быть повторено выражение всей первой группы
    .)*?          # или любой символ, много раз
   )
 \)
)
```

Все выражение целиком выглядит так:

```
(\(((?:(?1)|.)*?)\))({((?:(?3)|.)*?)})
```

Требуемые результаты в 2 и 4 группах захвата. Если внутри первых круглых скобок вложенности быть не может, то начало можно сократить до того, как вы изначально пробовали, т.е. до `\((.*?)\)`. Тогда еще надо будет не забыть поменять ссылку `(?3)`

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TqIezr/1)

**UPD:**
Исходя из комментария "*Круглые скобки содержат имя параметра, фигурные содержат параметры. Параметр может содержать другие параметры*", в случае если поддержки рекурсии в вашем диалекте регулярных выражений нет можно применить:

```
 \((.*?)\){(.*)}
```

Первый захват не жадный, до первой встреченной круглой скобки, второй - жадный, захватит все до последней фигурной скобки, если других фигурных скобок в строке не будет, такого выражения будет достаточно